# SQL state [null]; error code [17004]; Invalid column type; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: Invalid column type

Tags: java, spring, oracle

i have a problem with my query i don't know how to deal with oracle but when i try the same code for SQL it's working but it's showing me the above error while compiling i think the problem is in the query , please someone help if knew how to deal with this.
thanks

// First class

```
package com.caveofprogramming.spring.test;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.List;
import javax.sql.DataSource;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.RowMapper;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.namedparam.BeanPropertySqlParameterSource;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.namedparam.MapSqlParameterSource;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

    @Component
    ("offersDao")
    public class OffersDAO {
        private JdbcTemplate jdbc;
        @Autowired`enter code here`
        public void setDataSource(DataSource jdbc) {
            this.jdbc = new JdbcTemplate(jdbc);
        }
    public boolean create(Offer offer) {
    BeanPropertySqlParameterSource params = new BeanPropertySqlParameterSource(offer);
    return jdbc.update("INSERT INTO offers " + " ( id, name, email, text) "
                    + " VALUES " + " ( :id, :name, :email, :text) ", params) == 1;
    }
    }
```

// 2nd class

```
package com.caveofprogramming.spring.test;

public class Offer {

    private int id;
    private String name;
    private String email;
    private String text;

    public Offer() {

    }

    public Offer(int id, String name, String email, String text) {

        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.email = email;
        this.text = text;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public String getText() {
        return text;
    }

    public void setText(String text) {
        this.text = text;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Offer [id=" + id + ", name=" + name + ", email=" + email
                + ", text=" + text + "]";
    }

}
```

//3rd  main class

```
package com.caveofprogramming.spring.test;

import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.dao.DataAccessException;
import org.springframework.jdbc.CannotGetJdbcConnectionException;

public class App {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(
                "com/caveofprogramming/spring/test/beans/beans.xml");

        OffersDAO offersDao = (OffersDAO) context.getBean("offersDao");

        try {

            Offer offer1 = new Offer(10, "khan", "G@G.com", "GG");
            Offer offer2 = new Offer(11, "khan", "M@G.com", "GG");
            Offer offer3 = new Offer(12, "khan", "V@G.com", "GG");
            offersDao.create(offer1);
            offersDao.create(offer2);
            offersDao.create(offer3);

        } catch (CannotGetJdbcConnectionException ex) {
            System.out.println("Unable to connect to database");
        } catch (DataAccessException ex) {
            System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
            System.out.println(ex.getClass());
        }

        ((ClassPathXmlApplicationContext) context).close();
    }

}
```

Comment: If you think the problem is with the query then it might be a good idea to actually include it.... it would also be a good idea to include the table definition(s) of the table(s) that query is hitting.

Comment: Without posting relevant code, no one can help you. Downvoting. You can refer how to ask a question by checking http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and how to create an example by reading this : http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @JonK thanks bro , i am trying to include  my whole java classes but for some strange reason not working ..      query is    return jdbc.update("INSERT INTO offers " + " ( id, name, email, text) " + " VALUES " + " ( :id, :name, :email, :text) " , params)==1;

Comment: @Faisal [Use the edit link](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/33239193/edit)

Comment: @jonk bro i think something is wrong in this fuction                         public boolean create(Offer offer) {
BeanPropertySqlParameterSource params = new BeanPropertySqlParameterSource(offer);
return jdbc.update("INSERT INTO offers  ( id, name, email, text)  VALUES  ( :id, :name, :email, :text) ", params) == 1;
}                          // Because why it's not working for oracle though i tried to put the data directly it's working but not when i try to pass the object then i get totally disappoint :(  bro Any idea what could be the issue. ? thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

```
  i tried 





       public boolean create (Offer offer){

        return jdbc.update("insert into offers (firstno,secondno,thirldno) values
     ( '" +offer.getFirstno() + "', '" +offer.getSecondno() +"' ,'"+offer.getThirldno()+"')")==1;

 }
```

instead of

```
  public boolean create(Offer offer) {
    BeanPropertySqlParameterSource params = new BeanPropertySqlParameterSource(offer);
    return jdbc.update("INSERT INTO offers " + " ( id, name, email, text) "
                    + " VALUES " + " ( :id, :name, :email, :text) ", params) == 1;
    }
```

and now it's working that way .
Well , it's not answer to me but anyhow this is what i find out to deal with the above  error an another way but i still didn't find out what could be the error in the previous query . 
thanks to ALL of you friends :) Happy Coding